# How to check for stability of a LARGE system of linear difference equations

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, stability-theory

I have large system of difference equations in this form:

[image]

[image]

Each function ($x$) is represented by $n$-th order difference equations of all the the other functions.

Background:

Each function ($x$) is an approximation of an arbitrary set of data points.
There is unique data set for each function ($x$)

The Coefficients ($A$) are solved for such that each function best approximates it's corresponding data set.

Problem:

When I use the set of equations with optimized coefficients to predict future data points I find that most function go off to infinity (positive & negative)
This indicates that the set of equations, while optimize, is not stable. I want to add a stability criteria when solving for the coefficients ($A$).

How can i do this?